# Meteor angular-meteor package

Tags: meteor, meteor-blaze, angular-meteor

I  wasn't  able to use blaze and angularjs templates from within the same package, I had to disable one of them in order to not get and and get an output .
How can I achieve that?

Comment: This is not enough information to help you. What was the error or problem you ran into when using both? Also, what do you mean by using them in the same package and disabling one? Are you really talking about a package or a project?

Comment: have you tried the tutorial: http://angular-meteor.com/tutorial

Answer (score 0, accepted):

for using Blaze and Angular together you should use the `meteor-include` directive.  here are the API docs with examples:
http://angular-meteor.com/api/meteor-include